# What does the value in SEC FORM 13F mean?

Tags: stocks, sec, market-data, edgar

13F-HR table has a value field, e.g. https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1726609/000108514624000840/xslForm13F_X02/infotable.xml

I'm wondering if it means the fair value of the shares at that period, or the average price the institution paid for that amount of shares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column 4 is the fair market value.

References from the [Form 13F instructions](https://www.sec.gov/files/form13f.pdf):

- Special Instruction 8:

  > 8. In determining fair market value, use the value at the close of trading on the last trading day of the calendar year or quarter, as appropriate. Enter values rounded to the nearest dollar.
- Special Instruction 11(b)(iv):

  > iv. Column 4. Market Value. Enter in Column 4 the market value of the holding of the particular class of security as prescribed by Special Instruction 8.